# help with linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having a hard time doing proofs, if someone could explain how to do this, then that would be great. Thanks

Prove that if $S = \{v_k\}_{k=1}^r$ is a linearly dependent set of
vectors in a vector space $V$, and if $v_{r+1}, \ldots , v_n$ are any vectors
in $V$ that are not in $S$, then $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots , v_r , v_{r+1}, . . . , v_n\}$ is also linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Since $S$ is linearly dependent, let $(\lambda_i)_{i\in\{1,\ldots,r\}}\in k^r\setminus\{0\}$ such that : $$\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_iv_i=0.$$
Let define for all $i\in\{r+1,\ldots,n\}$ : $$\lambda_i=0.$$
Then $(\lambda_i)_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\in k^n\setminus\{0\}$ and one has : $$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iv_i=\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_iv_i=0.$$
Therefore, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r,v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent.